# Tkinter Label() Counter Variable

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I am currently working on a Tkinter GUI rock paper scissors game. I want to be able to calculate and store the # of wins the user, computer have and the # of ties. I have been able to set up a IntVar() textvariable to associate with the label, and i have it count up everytime the user wins. But the only problem is, it only counts up one, for example (user draws 'Rock' and computer draws 'Scissors' [We know that the user wins, ] but the next time the user draws rock, and the computer draws scissors the count goes down back to 0). It only counts up once and resets and doesnt go to the next integer (so it goes 0 to 1, then back to 0 and not 2). Can someone help me make a successful counter variable that counts the # of wins and ties.

***Code:***

```
#Written by : Pamal Mangat.
#Written on : Monday, July 27th, 2015.
#Rock Paper Scissors : Version 1.2 (Tkinter [GUI] addition)

from tkinter import *
from sys import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame as py
import os
from random import randrange

py.init()

#Function runs the actual game. 
def runGame(startWindow):

    #Close [startWindow] before advancing:
    startWindow.destroy()
    startWindow.quit()

    master = Tk()
    master.title('Lets Play!')

    #Function carries on the remainder of the game.
    def carryGame(button_id):

        #Initial Values
        userWins = 0
        ties = 0
        computerWins = 0

        label_one = Label(master, text='Player Wins: ', font='Helvetica 11 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        label_one.place(x=15, y=210)

        label_two = Label(master, text='Ties: ', font='Helvetica 11 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        label_two.place(x=195, y=210)

        label_three = Label(master, text='Computer Wins: ', font='Helvetica 11 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        label_three.place(x=295, y=210)

        userWin_Text = IntVar()
        userWin_Text.set(userWins)

        ties_Text = IntVar()
        ties_Text.set(ties)

        computerWin_Text = IntVar()
        computerWin_Text.set(computerWins)

        userWin_Label = Label(master, textvariable = userWin_Text, font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        userWin_Label.place(x=110, y=210)

        ties_Label = Label(master, textvariable = ties_Text, font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        ties_Label.place(x=240, y=210)

        computerWin_Label = Label(master, textvariable = computerWin_Text, font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        computerWin_Label.place(x=420, y=210)

        result = StringVar()
        printResult = Label(master, textvariable = result, font='Bizon 32 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        printResult.place(x=130, y=300)

        #Computer's move:
        random_Num = randrange(1,4)

        if random_Num == 1:
           computer_Move = 'Rock     '
           result.set(computer_Move)

        elif random_Num == 2:
            computer_Move = 'Paper     '
            result.set(computer_Move)

        else:
            computer_Move = 'Scissors'
            result.set(computer_Move)

        if button_id == 1:
            player_Move = 'Rock'

        elif button_id == 2:
            player_Move = 'Paper'

        else:
            player_Move = 'Scissors'

        if player_Move == 'Rock' and computer_Move == 'Scissors':
            userWins += 1
            userWin_Text.set(userWins)


    #Rock button
    rock_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(1))
    rock_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\rock.png')
    rock_Button.config(image=rock_photo,width="120",height="120")
    rock_Button.place(x=17, y=70)

    #Paper button
    paper_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(2))
    paper_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\paper.png')
    paper_Button.config(image=paper_photo,width="120",height="120")
    paper_Button.place(x=167, y=70)

    #Scissors button
    scissors_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(3))
    scissors_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\scissors.png')
    scissors_Button.config(image=scissors_photo,width="120",height="120")
    scissors_Button.place(x=317, y=70)

    label_1 = Label(master, text='Please make your selection-', font='Bizon 20 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
    label_1.pack(side=TOP)

    label_2 = Label(master, text='The computer picked:', font='Helvetica 22 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
    label_2.place(x=70, y=240)

    #Locks window size
    master.maxsize(450, 400)
    master.minsize(450, 400)

    #Sets window background to PeachPuff2
    master.config(background='PeachPuff2')

    master.mainloop()

def startScreen():

    #Plays music for the application
    def playMusic(fileName):
        py.mixer.music.load(fileName)
        py.mixer.music.play()

    #Start Window
    startWindow = Tk()
    startWindow.title('[Rock] [Paper] [Scissors]')

    #Imports image as title
    load = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\title.png')
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    img = Label(startWindow, image=render, bd=0)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=-100, y=-65)

    clickToPlay = Button(startWindow, text='Play!', width=8, font='Bizon 20 bold', bg='Black', fg='Yellow', relief=RIDGE, bd=0, command=lambda:runGame(startWindow))
    clickToPlay.place(x=75, y=125)

    #Credit
    authorName = Label(startWindow, text='Written by : Pamal Mangat', font='Times 6 bold', bg='Black', fg='Yellow')
    authorName.place(x=2, y=230)

    versionNum = Label(startWindow, text='[V 1.2]', font='Times 6 bold', bg='Black', fg='Red')
    versionNum.place(x=268, y=230)

    #Start Screen Music
    playMusic(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Audio\title_Song.mp3')

    #Locks window size
    startWindow.maxsize(300, 250)
    startWindow.minsize(300, 250)

    #Sets window background to black
    startWindow.config(background='Black')

    startWindow.mainloop()

startScreen()
```

***ScreenShots:***

An image of the produced window: 
[image]

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; most of what you've provided is not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-initializing your counter variables every time `carryGame` is run. Extract them to a higher level of scope so that they are only initialized once:

EDIT: Try this

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame as py
import os
from random import randrange



#Initial Values
userWins = 0
ties = 0
computerWins = 0
py.init()


#Function runs the actual game. 
def runGame(startWindow):

    #Close [startWindow] before advancing:
    startWindow.destroy()
    startWindow.quit()

    master = Tk()
    master.title('Lets Play!')

    #Function carries on the remainder of the game.
    def carryGame(button_id):

        #Initial Values
        global userWins
        global ties
        global computerWins

        label_one = Label(master, text='Player Wins: ', font='Helvetica 11 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        label_one.place(x=15, y=210)

        label_two = Label(master, text='Ties: ', font='Helvetica 11 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        label_two.place(x=195, y=210)

        label_three = Label(master, text='Computer Wins: ', font='Helvetica 11 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        label_three.place(x=295, y=210)

        userWin_Text = IntVar()
        userWin_Text.set(userWins)

        ties_Text = IntVar()
        ties_Text.set(ties)

        computerWin_Text = IntVar()
        computerWin_Text.set(computerWins)

        userWin_Label = Label(master, textvariable = userWin_Text, font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        userWin_Label.place(x=110, y=210)

        ties_Label = Label(master, textvariable = ties_Text, font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        ties_Label.place(x=240, y=210)

        computerWin_Label = Label(master, textvariable = computerWin_Text, font='Helvetica 10 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        computerWin_Label.place(x=420, y=210)

        result = StringVar()
        printResult = Label(master, textvariable = result, font='Bizon 32 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
        printResult.place(x=130, y=300)

        #Computer's move:
        random_Num = randrange(1,4)

        if random_Num == 1:
           computer_Move = 'Rock     '
           result.set(computer_Move)

        elif random_Num == 2:
            computer_Move = 'Paper     '
            result.set(computer_Move)

        else:
            computer_Move = 'Scissors'
            result.set(computer_Move)

        if button_id == 1:
            player_Move = 'Rock'

        elif button_id == 2:
            player_Move = 'Paper'

        else:
            player_Move = 'Scissors'

        if player_Move == 'Rock' and computer_Move == 'Scissors':
            userWins += 1
            userWin_Text.set(userWins)


    #Rock button
    rock_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(1))
    rock_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\rock.png')
    rock_Button.config(image=rock_photo,width="120",height="120")
    rock_Button.place(x=17, y=70)

    #Paper button
    paper_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(2))
    paper_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\paper.png')
    paper_Button.config(image=paper_photo,width="120",height="120")
    paper_Button.place(x=167, y=70)

    #Scissors button
    scissors_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(3))
    scissors_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\scissors.png')
    scissors_Button.config(image=scissors_photo,width="120",height="120")
    scissors_Button.place(x=317, y=70)

    label_1 = Label(master, text='Please make your selection-', font='Bizon 20 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
    label_1.pack(side=TOP)

    label_2 = Label(master, text='The computer picked:', font='Helvetica 22 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
    label_2.place(x=70, y=240)

    #Locks window size
    master.maxsize(450, 400)
    master.minsize(450, 400)

    #Sets window background to PeachPuff2
    master.config(background='PeachPuff2')

    master.mainloop()

def startScreen():

    #Plays music for the application
    def playMusic(fileName):
        py.mixer.music.load(fileName)
        py.mixer.music.play()

    #Start Window
    startWindow = Tk()
    startWindow.title('[Rock] [Paper] [Scissors]')

    #Imports image as title
    load = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\title.png')
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    img = Label(startWindow, image=render, bd=0)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=-100, y=-65)

    clickToPlay = Button(startWindow, text='Play!', width=8, font='Bizon 20 bold', bg='Black', fg='Yellow', relief=RIDGE, bd=0, command=lambda:runGame(startWindow))
    clickToPlay.place(x=75, y=125)

    #Credit
    authorName = Label(startWindow, text='Written by : Pamal Mangat', font='Times 6 bold', bg='Black', fg='Yellow')
    authorName.place(x=2, y=230)

    versionNum = Label(startWindow, text='[V 1.2]', font='Times 6 bold', bg='Black', fg='Red')
    versionNum.place(x=268, y=230)

    #Start Screen Music
    playMusic(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Audio\title_Song.mp3')

    #Locks window size
    startWindow.maxsize(300, 250)
    startWindow.minsize(300, 250)

    #Sets window background to black
    startWindow.config(background='Black')

    startWindow.mainloop()

startScreen()
```

Here is an image of the code being executed:
(It does the counting correctly)
[image]

But as soon as a different command is executed (diff. button is pressed) the count goes to being 0.
[image]

But if the user wins again, then the count re appears. 
[image]

SO HOW DO I KEEP THE NUMBER ON THE SCREEN AT ALL TIMES??

Comment: Does the global attribute keyword make the variables global (what does it do)? And yes i know this may sound like a dumb question.

Comment: And also how would i make them count everytime the user wins?

Comment: And also what is a higher level of scope?

Comment: 1. [The `global` keyword is needed to tell your method that it is accessing a global variable.](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php) You should initialize these variables to 0 just once, and you can do it right before you call `py.init()`.
2. You already make them count every time the user wins in your code (i.e. `userWins += 1`)
3. [The "scope" roughly refers to which variables/functions/methods etc are accessible at any given time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

Comment: Okay one final thing, the counting variable is exectuing correctly and is displaying a +1 number everytime a user wins, but at most times it is stuck at 0, and only updates once i clikc the button again, how do i keep the updated # (for example user wins and the zero becomes a 1. But the next time the computer wins it resets back to 0 untill the user wins again, ) If that didnt make sense you can ask me to rephrase the question but could you help me?

Comment: By using a global variable, every time  `userWins += 1` is called the count will go up and **will persist** if you don't re-initialize the counter every time the game is run. Do not set
        userWins = 0
        ties = 0
        computerWins = 0 
within `def carryGame(button_id):`

Comment: I've supplied some screenshots in the edit, sorry im still new to to stackoverflow, but yeah if you can see the images and tell me if you know what, im doing wrong?? :(